# Working with data & basic R programming

Tags: r, average

I'm new into R (and stackoverflow) and I am having a little problem with (I think) is a very easy thing to do.

Basically I have some data, for example:

```
ID | Data
----------
1 | 20
----------
2 | 30
----------
3 | 25
----------
4 | 26
----------
5 | 88
----------
6 | 65
----------
7 | 70
----------
8 | 30
----------
9 | 15
----------
10| 22
----------
```

What I want to do is:

1. Take the 3 first observations
2. Calculate the average of those 3 observations
3. Save that into another matrix or data frame with its own ID
4. And continue with the other 3 observations.

So if I have 15 observations I would end with only 5 in this example.

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to R and StackOverflow! You're going to find that people are much, much more willing to help you answer questions if you've provided some examples of what you've tried already. So, with that in mind, what are your initial thoughts on how to solve these questions? Answers best provided in the question, and not in the comments here.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions @brittenb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We create grouping variable with `%/%` and use `aggregate` from `base R` to get the `mean` of the 'Data' column

```
df1$grp <- (seq_len(nrow(df1))-1) %/%3 + 1
aggregate(Data~grp, df1, FUN = mean)
#  grp     Data
#1   1 25.00000
#2   2 59.66667
#3   3 38.33333
#4   4 22.00000
```

The `%/%` indicates integer division.  For example, if we use the integer division on a sequence of 10

```
(1:10-1) %/% 3 + 1
#[1] 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 4
```

Note that 1 is added at the end to make the group start from 1 rather than 0, but it is just a choice

Comment: OP is new to R. Maybe try explaining some of the stuff you're using like `%/%` and the formula notation.

Answer (score 2):

A similar solution but using `data.table` would be:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, mean(Data), by = .(((seq_len(nrow(df))-1) %/% 3) + 1)]

#   seq_len       V1
#1:       1 25.00000
#2:       2 59.66667
#3:       3 38.33333
#4:       4 22.00000
```

This is nice because `data.table`'s `by` takes expressions so you don't need to create a new variable. *Credit goes to akrun for the calculation of the groups*.

---

A little background:

From the `data.table` vignette:

> data.table inherits from data.frame. It offers fast and nemory efficient: file reader and writer, aggregations, updates, equi, non-equi, rolling, range and interval joins, in a short and flexible syntax, for faster development.

`data.table`'s can have a very different syntax than `data.frames`. In this instance, we specify the calculation we want to perform (the `mean(Data)`) and then we also tell `data.table` what to group by - in this case the expression `((seq_len(nrow(df))-1) %/% 3) + 1`, which evaluates to a numeric vector that is indexed by 1 every 4th element:

```
((seq_len(nrow(df))-1) %/% 3) + 1
 [1] 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 4
```

This then returns the output you see above.

**Data:**

```
df <- structure(list(ID = 1:10, Data = c(20L, 30L, 25L, 26L, 88L, 65L, 
       70L, 30L, 15L, 22L)), .Names = c("ID", "Data"), row.names = c(NA, 
       -10L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x00000000063e0788>)
```

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this is to first create a grouping variable. This variable will allow us to `split` the dataset into our groups and then find the mean. We can then combine the means and their ids into a new dataframe.

Let's start with the grouping variable. We'll take advantage of the modulus `%%` to do this.

```
set.seed(9025)
df = data.frame(id=1:10, values=sample(1:100, 10, FALSE))
df$group = df$id - (df$id %% -3)

df
   id values group
1   1     85     3
2   2      2     3
3   3     93     3
4   4     47     6
5   5     90     6
6   6      1     6
7   7     27     9
8   8     57     9
9   9     81     9
10 10      3    12
```

Now we can `split` by our group variable.

```
dl = split(df, df$group)
dl
$`3`
  id values group
1  1     85     3
2  2      2     3
3  3     93     3

$`6`
  id values group
4  4     47     6
5  5     90     6
6  6      1     6

$`9`
  id values group
7  7     27     9
8  8     57     9
9  9     81     9

$`12`
   id values group
10 10      3    12
```

`split` just breaks the dataframe up by the variable that we feed it. So the first dataframe is just the subset of `df` where `df$group` is equal to 3. The actual value of `df$group` doesn't matter since we're not going to use it. We just needed to make sure we were getting three rows at a time.

Next, we just loop over the `list`, and calculate the mean

```
means = unname(sapply(dl, function(x) mean(x$values), simplify=TRUE))
means
60 46 55  3
```

And lastly, we just turn it into a new dataframe.

```
n = length(means)
new_df = data.frame(id=1:n, mean=means)
new_df
  id mean
1  1   60
2  2   46
3  3   55
4  4    3
```

In summary, the algorithm looks like this:

```
df$group = df$id - (df$id %% -3)
dl = split(df, df$group)
means = unname(sapply(dl, function(x) means(x$values), simplify=TRUE)
n = length(means)
new_df = data.frame(id=1:n, mean=means)
```